# Swift swipe from left to right

Tags: iphone, swipe

We all know that iOS has pretty cool feature, which is that swiping from right to left brings the DELETE button by default and the delete logic for it but it can be custom but anyway the important thing is that it is default and easy to implement.

During lots of Google researches I found NO TUTORIAL or even a little example of on how to get from left to right swipe and same logic like delete for it.

I have a table cell view and for each item that logic for deleting implemented. My boss wants left to right swipe and with custom button inside with custom logic, but I have no clue on how to achieve this, and Google did not give any results. Please kindly help me and guide me.

Comment: My google search was for `uitableviewcell actions left side`.

Comment: bro i think here is what you are looking for [link](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell)

Comment: bro wonderfull thanks a lot put this as answer! ill accept

Comment: He can't post an answer because the question has been closed as a duplicate. The "WHAT" that your question is "DUPLICATED OF" is linked at the top of your question. That earlier question has an answer with links to a tutorial, a library on github to do it for you, and yet another question about the same topic, and *that* question has a bunch of answers, including one with a link to the same github project linked by @ShehzadAli above.